# HTTPS on app store - what is the process?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, encryption, asihttprequest

(I think this question has been asked before, but the answers have been contradictory and may be out-of-date by now)

I'm creating an app which uses HTTPS, using the ASIHTTPRequest library.

My company is based in the UK, and the app will only be released in the UK.

Do I need to say my app contains encryption, and if so what are the steps required for compliance? Specifically for a non-US company?

Comment: I would try looking at the App HIG for your specific location.  Also, http://apple.stackexchange.com/ might have better answers.

Comment: Short answer: no. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802879/iphone-and-crypto-libraries

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SSL in an iPhone App - Export Compliance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128927/using-ssl-in-an-iphone-app-export-compliance)

Comment: @chown apple.stackexchange.com is for users, not developers.

Comment: @JosephH Oh, I thought it was for general "how does apple do this" (and of course the "how can I make my apple product do that").  That would be cool if it evolved into being used for both devs and users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://tigelane.blogspot.com/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html) is a fantastic blog post which really helped me with situations like this when using HTTPS API's

> Depending on where you go, and what you read you might think you don't need to do anything.  That's wrong.  If you application uses encryption (including SSL and HTTPS, possible other public domain encryption) then you need to get at least get an ERN before submitting your app to Apple for approval.

Some do get away with saying that no encryption is included even with a toggle to enable SSL on some applications but if you really want to be on the safe side then it's best if you get the certificate.

Another Article I found: http://blog.theanimail.com/iphone-encryption-export-compliance-for-apps

Comment: Yes, I read that. But from the comments, it seems that the process in for US folks only.

Comment: http://blog.theanimail.com/iphone-encryption-export-compliance-for-apps - the process described here is out of date, CCATS is not the way anymore. The ERN way in your first link is the right way.

Comment: @cannyboy that ERN process is for everyone, lots of non-US folks have done it, myself included.